# get particular element in nested vector C++

Tags: c++

I have a nested vector of strings like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>>
```

I want to access eight element of inner vector which is itself second element of outer vector.

Comment: `v[1][7]` doesn't work for you?

Comment: `std::vector` has `operator []` overloaded. So it's the same as a normal array.

Comment: It's probably worth adding that unless this is a one-time, exceptional case, you should probably define a class to wrap it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you would with a two-dimensional array:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;
// Fill it
std::cout << vec[1][7] << std::endl;
```

If you want bounds checking, use `std::vector::at`:

```
std::cout << vec.at(1).at(7) << std::endl;
```

Note that the indices are 1 and 7 because indexing starts at 0.